# Sharepoint app using client secret without Azure ACS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, acs

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around my current situation. My client is giving me as a configuration a Client ID and a Client Secret to configure a sharepoint add-in that is installed on premise.

Currently the authentication isn't working and it gives me the following error

```
Error when get token for app i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|844dcd97-5092-4b8f-9582-d80e0b0eb170@19dad6b1-b028-4aea-a5a4-baa784178ad2, exception: 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The Azure Access Control service is unavailable.    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSecurityTokenServiceDiscoveryManager.DiscoverApplicationSecurityTokenService(SPServiceContext serviceContext)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationServices.SPApplicationContext..ctor(SPServiceContext serviceContext, SPIdentityContext userIdentity, OAuth2EndpointIdentity applicationEndPoint)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForApplicationContext(SPIdentityContext userIdentityContext, String applicationId, Uri applicationRealm, SPApplicationContextAccessTokenType applicationTokenType, SPApplicationDelegationConsentType consentValue)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServerToAppServerAccessTokenManager.GetAccessTokenPrivate(SPServiceContext serviceContext, String appId, Uri appEndpointUrl, SPAppPrincipalInfo appPrincipal, SPApplicationContextAccessTokenType tokenType, Boolean useThreadIdentity, SPUserToken userToken)
```

The IT department is telling me that Azure ACS is not configured (and not supposed to be). So I'm left wondering why I get this error "The Azure Access Control service is unavailable"

Also, from what I understand the client secret is used **only** when dealing with Azure ACS (like the follogin image says), so I'm a bit lost

[image]

Any ideas?